# can't find crate `rustc` even with `rustc_private`

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

I stole this code from a tutorial and put it in `src/lib.rs`

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]
#![feature(plugin_registrar)]

extern crate rustc;
extern crate syntax;

use rustc::plugin::Registry;

use syntax::ast::{Item, MetaItem};
use syntax::codemap::Span;
use syntax::ext::base::ExtCtxt;
use syntax::ext::base::SyntaxExtension::Modifier;
use syntax::parse::token::intern;
use syntax::ptr::P;

#[plugin_registrar]
pub fn registrar(reg: &mut Registry) {
    reg.register_syntax_extension(intern("extension"), Modifier(Box::new(expand)));
}

fn expand(_: &mut ExtCtxt, _: Span, _: &MetaItem, item: P<Item>) -> P<Item> {
    println!("Hello world!");
    return item;
}
```

and `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "inductive"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["fakedrake"]

[lib]
name = "inductive"
plugin=true
[dependencies]
```

But

```
$ rustup component add rustc-dev 
info: downloading component 'rustc-dev'
info: installing component 'rustc-dev'
info: using up to 500.0 MiB of RAM to unpack components
102.5 MiB / 102.5 MiB (100 %)  18.9 MiB/s in  5s ETA:  0s
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.52.0-nightly (c68432f1e 2021-03-02)
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.52.0-nightly (caca2121f 2021-03-05)
$ cargo build --verbose
   Compiling inductive v0.1.0 (/Users/fakedrake/Projects/Rust/inductive)
     Running `rustc --crate-name inductive src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type dylib --emit=dep-info,link -C prefer-dynamic -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=9adf86ab36dcd7bb --out-dir /Users/fakedrake/Projects/Rust/inductive/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/Users/fakedrake/Projects/Rust/inductive/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/Users/fakedrake/Projects/Rust/inductive/target/debug/deps`
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `rustc`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:1
  |
4 | extern crate rustc;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `inductive`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name inductive src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type dylib --emit=dep-info,link -C prefer-dynamic -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=9adf86ab36dcd7bb --out-dir /Users/fakedrake/Projects/Rust/inductive/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/Users/fakedrake/Projects/Rust/inductive/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/Users/fakedrake/Projects/Rust/inductive/target/debug/deps` (exit code: 1)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try using `rustup component add rustc-dev --toolchain nightly`

Comment: Unfortunately no changr

Comment: Your tutorial is outdated. None of those crates exist anymore in the Rust compiler. `libsyntax` hasn't existed in `rustc` for around a year.

Comment: Is it deprecated (if so what is the replacement?) or am I supposed to install it separately?

Comment: It can't be installed; `libsyntax` is completely gone. It has been split up into multiple crates: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65324 Later the final remenants were moved to `librustc_ast` at which point it had just AST related code: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/69592

Comment: Compiler plugins were never released on stable (hence `#![feature(rustc_private)]`), but the modern way to do this would be [a proc-macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html), which have been stable for years.

Answer (score 4):

```
rustup component add --toolchain nightly rust-src rustc-dev llvm-tools-preview
```

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72564