# Can't find crate for `rustc_driver`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I tried to build the following rust file, and get an error.

`src/main.rs`:

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]

extern crate rustc_driver;

fn main() {
    let value = Some(42);
    //...
}
```

`cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "cargo_test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["XXX"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
```

errors:

```
(base) ➜  cargo_test git:(master) ✗ cargo build                           
   Compiling cargo_test v0.1.0 (XXX/cargo_test)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `rustc_driver`
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | extern crate rustc_driver;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `cargo_test`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

`rustc` version:

```
(base) ➜  cargo_test git:(master) ✗ rustc --version
rustc 1.53.0-nightly (673d0db5e 2021-03-23)
```

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't find crate \`rustc\` even with \`rustc\_private\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66523526/cant-find-crate-rustc-even-with-rustc-private)

Comment: @eggyal nope. After I run `rustup component add --toolchain nightly rust-src rustc-dev llvm-tools-preview`, I got `info: component 'rust-src' is up to date
info: component 'rustc-dev' for target 'x86_64-apple-darwin' is up to date
info: component 'llvm-tools-preview' for target 'x86_64-apple-darwin' is up to date`.

Comment: Does `ls $(dirname $(rustup which --toolchain nightly rustc))/../lib/librustc_driver-*.dylib` find anything?

Comment: @eggyal It just show `/XXX/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-034c1adc80d3ae5a.dylib`

Comment: Can you paste output from `cargo build -v` please?